# CPU prediction and memory barrier

Tags: caching, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers, branch-prediction

I'm learning memory barrier so I referred to [memory-barriers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt) documentation in linux kernel source code. And there is one description that I can't understand:

> Control dependencies can be a bit tricky because current compilers do
> not understand them.  The purpose of this section is to help you
> prevent the compiler's ignorance from breaking your code.
>
> A load-load control dependency requires a full read memory barrier,
> not simply a data dependency barrier to make it work correctly.
> Consider the following bit of code:
>
> ```
> q = READ_ONCE(a);
> if (q) {
>   <data dependency barrier>  /* BUG: No data dependency!!! */
>   p = READ_ONCE(b);
> }
> ```
>
> This will not have the desired effect because there is no actual data
> dependency, but rather a control dependency that the CPU may
> short-circuit by attempting to predict the outcome in advance, so that
> other CPUs see the load from b as having happened before the load from
> a.  In such a case what's actually required is:
>
> ```
> q = READ_ONCE(a);
> if (q) {
>   <read barrier>
>   p = READ_ONCE(b);
> }
> ```

And the following description is what confuse me:

> CPU may short-circuit by attempting to predict the outcome in advance,
> so that other CPUs see the load from b as having happened before the
> load from a

Does ***CPU prediction*** have something to do with ***other CPUs see the load from b as having happened before the load from a***? How does this happen?

Comment: Yes, speculative execution (based on branch prediction) means that control dependencies aren't like data dependencies, and later code doesn't have to wait for the branch condition.  `q = READ_ONCE(a)` / `p = READ_ONCE(array[q])` would have a data dependency, like C++ memory_order_consume.

Comment: @PeterCordes, What do you mean by **later code doesn't have to wait for the branch condition**? and what's the real effect of this?

Comment: @Peter Cordes, any futher explanation?

Comment: @PeterCordes, does this meaning that speculative execution (based on branch prediction) will make the code just like `q = READ_ONCE(a);p = READ_ONCE(b);` and thus cause the problem of **other CPUs see the load from b as having happened before the load from a**?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the Linux documentation is explaining.  Speculative *out-of-order* execution does speculate past branches instead of waiting for the branch direction to be known.