# Difference between data dependence and control dependence

Tags: dependencies, pipeline, cpu-architecture, branch-prediction, instruction-reordering

I'm struggling to understand the difference between data dependence and control dependence .

So what I saw as an example was :

**data dependence** e.g., instruction uses data created by another instruction

**control dependence** e.g., instruction waits to updated reg for comparison

What's hard for me to understand is that for example in beq I wait for the register to be updated but I also depend on his data.

So I don't know how to know the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

*instruction waits to updated reg for comparison* is a wrong description of control dependencies, no wonder

Conditional branch instructions themselves have a *data* dependency on their input register(s) before the branch condition can be checked.

**Instructions *after* the branch have a control dependency on the branch.**  The front-end needs to know which instructions to fetch/decode, based on whether the branch was taken or not.  (Or for indirect branches, what the target address was).

Branch prediction makes a guess that might later be discovered to be wrong.  (When the branch instruction actually executes and checks the prediction).

In simple (scalar) in-order pipelines, there's no way for dependent instructions to reach the exec stage before the branch instruction does.  Discovering and recovering from a branch mispredict just means re-steering the front-end to fetch from the correct address, discarding the instructions from the wrong path that had been fetched (and decoded).

But in out-of-order exec CPUs that can happen.  Especially if the branch's inputs were part of a long dependency chain, but the instructions with a control dependency on it don't have data dependencies.  (i.e. they're independent work that the out-of-order back-end can get started on speculatively.)

Branch prediction + speculative execution effectively hide control dependencies when the prediction is correct.  That's why compilers will often transform `if (a==0) return a;` into `if (a==0) return 0;` and similar; if they're going to branch anyway (control dependency), break / avoid the data dependency for the code using the return value.

Related:

- [What exactly happens when a skylake CPU mispredicts a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984007/what-exactly-happens-when-a-skylake-cpu-mispredicts-a-branch) - a modern OoO exec CPU.
- [Avoid stalling pipeline by calculating conditional early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932119/avoid-stalling-pipeline-by-calculating-conditional-early/49933702#49933702) - Minimizing the length of the data dependency chain for the branch itself, so it can execute early and verify the branch prediction.
- [Dependency chain analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739118/dependency-chain-analysis) mentions the control dependency of the loop branch.
- [CPU prediction and memory barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074851/cpu-prediction-and-memory-barrier) - speculative execution past branches can introduce memory reordering.
- [Why is a conditional move not vulnerable for Branch Prediction Failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131096/why-is-a-conditional-move-not-vulnerable-for-branch-prediction-failure) - CMOV is purely an ALU select operation, just a data dependency, not a control dependency.

  - [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875325/gcc-optimization-flag-o3-makes-code-slower-than-o2) shows how **CMOV can be slower, creating a loop-carried data dependency chain instead of a control dependency that speculative execution can hide.**