# Fastest way to mask out bytes higher than separator position with SIMD

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, simd, avx

`uint8_t data[] = "mykeyxyz:1234\nky:123\n...";`.
My lines of string has format `key:value`, where each line has `len(key) <= 16` guaranteed. I want to load `mykeyxyz` into a `__m128i`, but fill out the higher position with 0.

The easiest way is to have an array of 255 or 0 masks, but that requires another memory load.
Is there anyway to do this faster?

The accepted answer gives ~2% faster total program time. To compare, test `1brc_valid13.cpp` against `1brc_valid14.cpp` (which uses the accepted answer). Hardware: AMD 2950X, Ubuntu 18.04, g++ 11.4, compile command: `g++ -o main 1brc_final_valid.cpp -O3 -std=c++17 -march=native -m64 -lpthread`

**Edit:** preferably without AVX512

**Edit 2**: I need the variable `len` so I can start parsing the value part.

**Edit 3:** the function will be used in a loop (for example to parse 1 million lines of text). But `strcmp_mask` will basically always be inside L1 cache

**Edit 4:** I benchmark the functions by parsing 1 billion lines of `(key,value)` and process them. You can download the code/data and replicate the results in my repo: https://github.com/lehuyduc/1brc-simd . Also the discussion post will contain more info

**Edit 5:** I tested `maskafterc256` and found that it caused my code to be **50x slower!!!** If I replace `_mm256_set_epi8` with `_mm256_setr_epi8`, then it becomes **500+x slower** (took so long that I just Ctrl-C). I'm not sure what `_mm256_set_epi8` does, because it's translated into a sequence of instructions instead of a single one.

`perf stat -d ./main` result for `maskafterc`

```
         14,470.46 msec task-clock                #   20.785 CPUs utilized
             3,032      context-switches          #    0.210 K/sec
                 5      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
           341,894      page-faults               #    0.024 M/sec
    55,073,525,723      cycles                    #    3.806 GHz                      (37.19%)
     1,714,679,575      stalled-cycles-frontend   #    3.11% frontend cycles idle     (36.71%)
    11,442,758,125      stalled-cycles-backend    #   20.78% backend cycles idle      (36.92%)
    80,739,874,133      instructions              #    1.47  insn per cycle
                                                  #    0.14  stalled cycles per insn  (37.39%)
     8,661,529,181      branches                  #  598.566 M/sec                    (38.22%)
        39,299,214      branch-misses             #    0.45% of all branches          (38.13%)
    17,784,400,757      L1-dcache-loads           # 1229.015 M/sec                    (37.93%)
       827,509,870      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    4.65% of all L1-dcache hits    (37.52%)
   <not supported>      LLC-loads
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses

       0.696207306 seconds time elapsed

      12.918590000 seconds user
       1.546535000 seconds sys
```

`perf stat -d ./main` result for `maskafterc256`

```
Performance counter stats for './main':

      1,047,414.73 msec task-clock                #   29.982 CPUs utilized
           125,296      context-switches          #    0.120 K/sec
               211      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
           341,889      page-faults               #    0.326 K/sec
 4,229,832,527,830      cycles                    #    4.038 GHz                      (37.50%)
    10,965,796,240      stalled-cycles-frontend   #    0.26% frontend cycles idle     (37.50%)
   167,711,051,408      stalled-cycles-backend    #    3.96% backend cycles idle      (37.49%)
   296,573,918,148      instructions              #    0.07  insn per cycle
                                                  #    0.57  stalled cycles per insn  (37.50%)
    44,843,867,352      branches                  #   42.814 M/sec                    (37.50%)
        56,509,334      branch-misses             #    0.13% of all branches          (37.51%)
    91,621,829,978      L1-dcache-loads           #   87.474 M/sec                    (37.50%)
    18,776,996,709      L1-dcache-load-misses     #   20.49% of all L1-dcache hits    (37.51%)
   <not supported>      LLC-loads
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses

      34.935225940 seconds time elapsed

    1039.609651000 seconds user
       6.774492000 seconds sys
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

alignas(4096) const uint8_t strcmp_mask[32] = {
  255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
};

int main()
{
  uint8_t data[] = "mykeyxyz:1234\naaaaaaaaaaa";
  __m128i chars = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)data);
  __m128i separators = _mm_set1_epi8(':');
  __m128i compared = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(chars, separators);
  uint32_t separator_mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(compared);
  uint32_t len = __builtin_ctz(separator_mask);
  
  cout << "len = " << len << "\n";
  __m128i mask = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(strcmp_mask + 16 - len));
  __m128i key_chars = _mm_and_si128(chars, mask);
  
  uint8_t res[16];
  memcpy(res, (char*)&key_chars, 16);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) cout << int(res[i]) << " ";
  cout << "\n";
}
// len = 8
// 109 121 107 101 121 120 121 122 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: AVX-512 (and probably SVE) where masking is a first-class optimization can do a bithack on a mask and use it directly.  e.g. `blsmsk` = `(mask-1)^mask` gives you a mask of the elements to keep, except that includes the separator.  Maybe unaligned load from `data+1` so the mask is offset, or adjust the bithack if there's one that doesn't include the mask.  Or maybe `bzhi(-1, std::countr_zero(mask))`.

Comment: Without AVX-512 or SVE, there are ways to turn a bitmask into a vector, but those also involve vector constants ([is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675)).  So a sliding window into a static constant has equal chance to cache-miss.  (Although loading a constant allows out-of-order exec, vs. a calculated load addr won't start resolving a cache miss until after ctz + address math) .  BTW, you only need to align it by 32, not 4096!

Comment: If you could limit key position to 0..7, you could use 64-bit integer math for bithacks on the compare result with `vpaddq` or whatever.  Even with 0..15, it might be worth the cost to manually do carry propagation for a 128-bit `-1` vs. movemask / ctz for scalar blsmsk.

Comment: Could you clarify how to use 64-bit int math to solve this with case 0..15 ?

Comment: Can two (or more) key-value pairs occur within 16 bytes? (e.g. `"k1:x\nk2:y\n..."`)

Comment: @chtz yes. For example `key1:1\nkey2:2`

Comment: It's actually not that bad since we only need `mask - 1` and XOR.  Subtracting 1 only affects the high 64 bits (with a borrow of 1) if the low half was zero, so vpxor-zero / `vpcmpeqq` then shuffle that up to the high half and add the 0 or -1.  (`vpslldq xmm, xmm, 8` to byte-shift it, shifting in zeros into the low half, then `vpaddq`).  So not counting generating constants (`[0, 1]` and a vpxor zero), inside a loop doing this on multiple strings we might have `vpcmpeqq` / `vpaddq` (low half) in parallel, `vpslldq` / `vpaddq` to get `mask-1`, then vpxor / vpand.  But this doesn't clear the :

Comment: Do you need to know the key length?  e.g. to know the address of the start of the value part?  If you do still need movemask / ctz for that, getting a mask without that isn't actually saving that work.

Comment: @PeterCordes `(mask-1) & (~mask)` would generate a mask excluding the `:`, I think (and would work on 64 bit integers as well)

Comment: For the example in the question, I need the key length

Comment: @chtz you're talking about `separator_mask` in the code right?

Comment: This works requiring only SSE4.1: https://godbolt.org/z/TfaEfoMjG (I'll post an answer for that)

Comment: @HuyLe if you need the length anyways, you should also state this in the question. An additional memory load is usually not that expensive (assuming the data is in L1 cache already).

Comment: [`pcmpistrm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpistrm) may also be worth a look

Comment: Omg, that code is wrong... How did it passed all tests... Wtf. Thanks for finding another error!

Comment: @PeterCordes i did it because somehow it's faster than passing the variable. Also I completely forgot that you can `mmap` larger than file size. Thanks! Anyway, could you comment on the repo next because we're going off topic now, I think amdins don't want that

Comment: Moved my last few comments into https://github.com/lehuyduc/1brc-simd/issues/3 since they're not about this SO question.

Comment: Wow, this is already one of the first google results for 'mask first i bytes of simd'. Guess I'll copy some things from here ;)

Comment: `_mm256_setr_epi8` with compile-time-constant args is just a constant.  `_mm256_set_epi8` puts the bytes in the other order.  I'm surprised a 256-bit vector version was 50x slower on your Zen 1, but your code is pretty sensitive to load-use latency from address to `tzcnt` result to find the end of the key.  As  https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html points out, Zen 1 has penalties for any 16-byte chunk of a load that cross a 32-byte boundary.  But he's mostly writing about throughput limits; IDK how much higher latency is for misaligned 256-bit vs. 128-bit.

Comment: IIRC, I wrote some about ideas for avoiding the latency critical-path bottleneck in https://github.com/lehuyduc/1brc-simd/issues/3 on your github project, like aligned loads and finding the newlines, so out-of-order exec has something to start on that doesn't depend on the `tzcnt`.  Also, [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726) - GCC `-mtune=znver1` doesn't split unaligned 256-bit loads the way it does for Sandybridge, so presumably it's not a disaster.

Comment: You probably have some kind of bug in your `maskafterc256` version.  The instruction count *should* be similar, but it's actually running many more instructions, as well as a much lower IPC.  So it's doing a different amount of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often find it interesting to see how others approach a problem, so here's my version. It only requires SSE2, but benefits from SSSE3, and BMI1 for the trailing zeros calculation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

// gcc maskafterc.c -o maskafterc.bin -O3 -march=native -Wall

__m128i maskafterc(__m128i input, uint8_t c, uint8_t* restrict pos) {
  // Finds first occurance of c in input and takes its position pos. 
  // Returns mask of 255s before pos, 0s on and after.
  // e.g. maskafterc([5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 9, uint8_t *pos)
  // sets pos = 4 and returns [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].
  __m128i index = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
  __m128i cmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(input, _mm_set1_epi8(c));
  uint32_t mmask = _mm_movemask_epi8(cmp);
  *pos = (mmask ? __builtin_ctz(mmask) : 16); // Return all -1s if c not found
  return _mm_cmplt_epi8(index, _mm_set1_epi8(*pos));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned char data[] = "mykeyxyz:98765211234\naaaaaaaaaaa";
  uint8_t pos;
  __m128i chars = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)data);
  __m128i res =_mm_and_si128(maskafterc(chars, ':', &pos), chars);
  if (pos < 16) puts((char*) &res);
  printf("keylen = %i\n", pos);
}
//mykeyxyz
//keylen = 8
```

EDIT: AVX2 version.

```
__m256i maskafterc256(__m256i input, uint8_t c, uint8_t* restrict pos) {
  // Finds first occurance of c in input and takes its position pos. 
  // Returns mask of 255s before pos, 0s on and after.
  __m256i index = _mm256_setr_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
                                  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
                                  17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
                                  25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31);
  __m256i cmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(input, _mm256_set1_epi8(c));
  uint32_t mmask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp);
  *pos = (mmask ? __builtin_ctz(mmask) : 32); // Return all -1s if c not found
  return _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(_mm256_set1_epi8(*pos), index);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have made more clarification about the input. It's a bunch of lines with `key:value` format, not just a single line. This code fails if there are 2 `:` in the same 16 bytes block

Comment: @HuyLe: Is it common to have multiple key:value pairs in one 16-byte block?  If so, consider looping over the set bits (with `blsr` / `countr_zero`, or the equivalent bithack which can compile to blsr) so you don't have to redo the load / compare / movemask for every tzcnt.  But I guess that makes the last iteration useless, the one that ends at the end of the vector instead of another `:`.  `blsr` can detect when you've cleared the last bit, so skip the tzcnt / copy for that.

Comment: @Simon:  `_mm_set1_epi8` only requires SSE2, but it's more efficient with SSSE3 (one `movd` + `pshufb` instead of movd / punpcklbw / pshuflw / pshufd.)  But interesting idea to  sum the indices that survive the mask.  You can do that with `_mm_sad_epu8(cmp, _mm_setzero_si128())` / `_mm_shuffle_epi32` to get the high qword to low / `_mm_add_epi32`.  Or since it only works for one unmasked index, `or` instead of `add`.

Comment: @PeterCordes let's say 1 million lines with that format. But most lines have length ~8-9, so rarely 2 lines fit into a 16-byte block

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to use `phminposuw` here?  Inverting the mask would give us a `0` in one byte of the word containing the match, rest FFFF, so the minpos will be the 0..7 index of that word, and the min value will be either FF00 or 00FF which we'd have to process into a byte index, `(idx<<1) - (-1 or 0)` perhaps.  But this still doesn't help us handle a vector that has other matches later: `00FF` is less than `FF00`, so the tiebreak of lowest index doesn't apply. And if we process them so each matching word is the same `pcmpeqw(cmp, 0)`, we'd have to separately index the data.

Comment: @HuyLe: You should put that in the question.  So you'll be calling this function a lot of times without too much memory access in between.  The first load of `strcmp_mask` might cache miss, but you'll amortize that over many uses.

Comment: @HuyLe Okay, if you have to take the first of possibly multiple occurrences of the key terminator then I think the simplest way would be to just use ctz and take the hit on hardware that doesn't have the instruction. I'll edit my answer to handle this.

Comment: Thank you! This is measurably faster in my heavy benchmark (parsing 1 billion lines); speedup the total program by ~2%. Idk how to measure it standalone against the current code, though.

Comment: @HuyLe: That's surprising.  What compiler / options on what CPU?  https://godbolt.org/z/MKhjKGezd shows your original version compiling with clang to 6 uops for Intel CPUs with `-O2 -march=x86-64-v3 -fPIE`, vs. 7 for an optimized version of this answer not including the `*pos` store. (Using `uint32_t mask` to avoid a movzx and stuff, and removing the check for no match by using `std::countr_zero` which guarantees returning 32 in that case.  32>15 so we get an all-ones mask.  Using `uint16_t` with that, compilers would rather branch or `mmask | (1<<16)` than actually use 16-bit `tzcnt ax,ax`)

Comment: GCC compiles the OP's original to 8 uops, including both a `mov eax, 16` that it could have folded into a RIP-relative `lea` or the addressing mode, and a `vpand   xmm0, xmm0, [rdx+rax]` with an indexed addressing mode that will un-laminate.  Of course that's the non-inline version; inlining into a loop it would depend on what other work there is between calls, so which constants could be kept in registers.

Comment: It is interesting that this is almost as few uops as the OP's version if both are well optimized, but the load from `.rodata` has no data dependency on the input.  (And it's a constant that can stay in a register in a loop that doesn't make any function calls between keys.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I've added more information about the benchmark. You can download and replicate it (or see the assembly). Thanks!

Comment: @HuyLe: Didn't realize you'd be testing this on Zen 1 / Zen+.  Last time you asked, you were testing on Zen 3.  I checked https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html and even Zen 1 has no penalty for a misaligned vector load as long as it doesn't cross a 32-byte boundary.  Misaligned stores that cross a 16-byte boundary have a penalty; I was remembering that some older AMDs had effects at boundaries narrower than a whole cache line, but the 16-byte boundary is apparently only important for stores.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for pointing out! That `memset` was added in the latest version because I switch from global variables to `malloc`. It doesn't affected older version because global variables are already initialized to zero

Comment: @HuyLe I eliminated the branching, which I think might improve performance.

Comment: @SimonGoater: in the OP's use-case, a not-found key might only happen as an error, or happen so rarely that it's better to branch on it.  A lot of later code depends on `pos`, so 1 cycle extra latency (for `or reg, 1<<16`) in the critical path from loading `input` (from an address which indirectly depended on the old `pos`) to getting the new `pos` can be worse, if there isn't enough instruction-level parallelism to keep the execution units busy given that bottleneck.  But yes, this can be a useful optimization for throughput, especially if we care about machines without `tzcnt`

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't understand what you mean. In the previous version pos was not set until after both the branch and the ctz calculation in the normal case (mmask != 0) which must be slower, no?

Comment: @SimonGoater: Control dependencies work differently from data dependencies.  With speculative execution, the correctness of branch prediction is checked later, not part of the critical path latency from `mmask` to `*pos`.  See [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875325) for a practical example of CMOV (branchless with a data dependency) being slower than branching in a predictable case.  Also [Difference between data dependence and control dependence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69056484).  Same effect that lets OoO exec CPUs overlap loop iters.

Comment: To put it another way, branches aren't part of critical path latency for data dependency chains, assuming correct branch prediction.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's crazy! I just tried some benchmarks and it confirmed that __builtin_ctz(0x10000 | mmask) is slower than (mmask ? __builtin_ctz(mmask) : 16). Guess I'd better change it back!! Interesting though. So much for branching being a performance killer!

Comment: It of course depends on the use-case; if `mmask` actually was zero in a hard-to-predict pattern with non-negligible frequency, ORing a bit into the input would be cheaper.  But the OP's use-case of unique(?) keys in a large file means at most one key will have zero length, or it's an error condition.  All else equal, fewer branches on the fast path is better, especially fewer *taken* branches (so it's up to the compiler's branch layout), but a longer dep chain isn't equal.

Comment: @SimonGoater eh, is there a way to do this same question but with `__m256i` ? There's no `_mm256_cmplt_epi8` instruction. It's too similar so idk if it can be posted as another Stackoverflow question. It's still for the use case in the question, just different input length distribution (imagine 95% of the time we use `__m128i`  for the hot loop, then 5% other time we use `__m256i`)

Comment: Obviously we can use `loadu` to get the mask like in my original answer. But I wonder if we can avoid it like in your answer

Comment: @HuyLe It's weird there's no AVX2 equivalent of cmplt. You can still do it though. I've taken a risk and posted an untested AVX2 version. All my hardware is pre-Haswell so I can't test it, but I think it should work as intended as it is.

Comment: Huh, why is there `cmpgt` but no `cmplt` on AVX2. I didn't even searched for `cmpgt` because there's no `cmplt` xD. The code is working, I'll test the performance later. Thanks!

Comment: The performance will suffer from the extra subtraction I expect. I think the best way to use these functions is to dismantle them and manually integrate them into your loop so the set doesn't need to be performed on every call. The compiler may already do this if it inlines them.

Comment: @HuyLe: There is no integer `pcmpltb` instruction for SSE2 either, the intrinsic just reverses the operands.  `x < y` via `y > x`.  My first reaction on reading the 128-bit version was that it was weird to formulate it in terms of an instruction that didn't exist (except with AVX-512 compare-into-mask), but then I remembered that the emulation had no extra cost, just reversing operands, so i didn't comment because there wasn't an actual problem or asm improvement.  But now there is, the AVX2 version is wasting a subtract on `32 - *pos` - you can just manually swap the operands.

Answer (score 7):

Your existing way is probably best for your use-case of processing a big batch of key:value lines.  You'll get at most one cache-miss for the sliding-window array on the first call, but it'll then be hot in L1d cache assuming you aren't touching huge amounts of memory before parsing the next `key:value`.  Unaligned vector loads are very cheap on modern x86 when they hit in cache, as long as they don't cross a cache-line boundary ([or 32-byte boundary on Zen 1](https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html)), and aligning your 32-byte constant array to its size prevents that.

You say you need the `__builtin_ctz(mask)` or `std::countr_zero(mask)` result anyway, and your current strategy only takes a couple extra instructions beyond that (like a `sub` or `neg` and then a memory-source `vpand`), so it's very good for throughput.

---

@chtz's answer shows a way to process the vector compare result directly into a vector mask, without going to scalar and back. It takes surprisingly few instructions even though there isn't a subtract or decrement that carries across the whole 128-bit vector, only within 64-bit elements.  Going to scalar with `_mm_movemask_epi8` makes the bithack easier, but applying it without AVX-512 would take even more work and require loading a non-trivial vector constant for any of the efficient approaches in *[is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675/5740428)*.  If you're going to load anything from `.rodata`, it might as well be the mask you want (Although that does make the load address data-dependent on the compare, so load-use latency is part of what out-of-order exec has to hide, and out-of-order exec can't start early on a cache miss.)

In a different use-case from yours, where data-cache misses are a problem for the sliding-window mask load, @chtz's answer is worth trying, and perhaps also this answer if AVX-512 is available.   (@Simon's answer is good but needs a vector constant: if you're doing enough work between calls that cache isn't still hot, it's probably not in a loop that can keep that constant in a register either.)

**With AVX-512, it's cheap to apply a scalar mask to a vector.**  This answer has some AVX-512 versions which avoid any vector constants, which might or might not be better than your sliding window or than chtz's answer. (AVX-512 makes chtz's code more efficient, combining the final `andnot` and `and` into one `vpternlogq` instruction).  chtz's AVX1 vector shuffles have the lowest critical-path latency for out-of-order exec to hide, but AVX-512 allows fewer total uops for the front-end and ROB (reorder buffer).  Especially when you also need `__builtin_ctz(mask)`.

AVX-512 also makes it cheaper for a compiler to do `_mm_set1_epi8(':')` with a mov-immediate + `vpbroadcastb` instead of loading a constant from `.rodata` for that.  (GCC 12 likes to construct constants that way even with out AVX-512, needing a separate `[v]movd` as well as `vpbroadcastd` or `pshufd`.  This costs more code size but less `.rodata` size (especially for large 32 and 64-byte constants), and can't miss in data cache.  Maybe GCC's tuning testing found that code was more predictable and easier for the CPU to prefetch than data, or that I-cache pressure wasn't as much of a problem on average.

---

Using AVX-512, you can generate a mask using [`_mm_maskz_broadcastb_epi8`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_maskz_broadcastb_epi&techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,AVX_512&ig_expand=567) for use with [`_mm_and_si128`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_and&ig_expand=4602,565,566,343,334,566,305&techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL).

Even more simply, you can mask the input characters with [`_mm_maskz_mov_epi8`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_maskz_mov_epi8&ig_expand=4602,565,566,343,334,566,305,4544,4545&techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL) <sup>(1)</sup>.  If you do another vector operation on the `__m128i`, the compiler might even be able to fold this zero-masking into the next operation.

**This versions uses the key length (`ctz`) so it's good for cases which need that as an extra output.**

```cpp
#if defined(__AVX512BW__) && defined(__BMI2__)
__m128i mask_first_n(__m128i string, int n) {
    //__mmask16 mask = (1u << n) - 1;      // compilers use shlx/sub
    __mmask16 mask = _bzhi_u32(-1u, n);    // same result for n=0..31.  For n=32, produces -1 instead of 0 (for 1u<<(n&31) like x86 shifts)
    return _mm_maskz_mov_epi8(mask, string);
}
#endif
```

```
mask_first_n(long long __vector(2), int):
        mov     eax, -1         # can potentially get hoisted out of a loop
        bzhi    eax, eax, edi
        kmovw   k1, eax
        vmovdqu8        xmm0{k1}{z}, xmm0
        ret
```

So this is 3 instructions after getting the `__builtin_ctz` result, not counting the `mov eax, -1` which could be reused across loop iterations if the loop has enough registers to spare.  They're all single-uop, except `kmov* k, r32` on Zen 4 which is 2 uops.  (https://uops.info/)

With `(1u << n) - 1`, we got `mov eax,1` / `shlx` / `sub eax,1`, which on Intel can run on any ALU port including 6 which doesn't have any vector ALUs, but that's 2 total uops.  `bzhi` is 1 uop on Intel and AMD, but on Intel only runs on port 1 or 5.  (Or on Alder Lake just port 1 since it has 3 cycle latency there.)

Using this, you can mask your string like this:

```cpp
int find(__m128i string, char c) {
// You do still want SSE/AVX compare+movemask here, not _mm_cmpeq_epi8_mask 
    __m128i compareMask = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(string, _mm_set1_epi8(c));
    unsigned mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(compareMask);
    return std::countr_zero(mask);    // or _tzcnt_u32 if you don't want C++20 <bit>
    // TODO: error handling if mask == 0, i.e. character not found
    //  _tzcnt_u32 or countr_zero returns 32
    //  and bzhi(-1, 32) and zero-masking will leave all 16 bytes unchanged
    //  either use 32-byte vectors, or std::countr_zero( mask | (1<<16) ) to get a "correct" len
}

__m128i zero_above_key_ctz_bzhi(__m128i vec, __m128i separator){
    int pos = find(vec, separator);
    __m128i result = mask_first_n(vec, pos);
    return result;
}


int main() {
    unsigned char data[] = "mykeyxyz:1234\naaaaaaaaaaa";
    __m128i chars = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)data);

    int pos = find(chars, _mm_set1_epi8(':'));
    __m128i result = mask_first_n(chars, pos);

    puts((char*) &result);
}
```

This code prints `mykeyxyz`.
See [live code at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoZAFI9AIQuXSS%2BsgJ4BlRugDCqWgFcWDCaRuADJ4DJgAcr4ARpjEIJIapAAOqAqEzgyePn4BKWlOAiFhkSwxcQl2mA4FDEIETMQEWb7%2BXJXVGXUNBEUR0bHxiQr1jc05bcPdvSVlgwCUdqjexMjsHBYAzKHIPlgA1GYb7ngsLKEExKEAdAiH2GYaAIKb27uYB0fIw5cmdw/Pei2DB23n2h3cXwI%2BFQfyeL2Bbw%2BEOG%2BEEsIBQJBYKOUUI6P%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%2Bv59geaAaRcXmxKgKoOZBCh7L%2BVXyk2CXjpOeD/m0/V6ByzZ7N5qCalmyXHnQyr0Ka7xiMqT5RAAngQmB9RpyDxcAQqDUmmCEKuB7eEoU2antB17GajgkAoYYkEGUKua1HkdT5EC6a%2BMaNgW4LghmHIcmOZ29kwnJ6GgxCqo4Fi6vQDAEgRRGPJxAYOvNFJMFEiGYBSLqYLtom1R%2BY2%2BrRDqvWG%2BN0QphVKbGdnJhGeRCaREDM0G7NMSQAVPHerMOluO69hlxkel6PpC3k4tqfZjlQTLu54c8ONwk8UtzZ1xOk2aFNUxTH7XUVLoM1xQtG/Rili9j3McQ%2BL5PmlGUGWJSSSSZtqwa6guYMg8l8aLLG63eco%2BxseZ%2Ba6AHRty%2BYAH5ZrZNbyi6LCIUFezrUXzZQXnBcmnleyKO8tJ0lwra8TKleYGlY6mqgeAtiu7yK72%2BeIYFCfvi6Zchy6GbJy6LNj%2Bg6AT1PmF7KnOdBXnTDz0XY8JVB%2BZJD4fUuqoDBfWOyCqkxm3cZp9SCLhEtx/KbYmJ2h1NsD17mXx7znF1aUQBSI0PYDIwwbGQMXK%2BwJdoclCMMNULZUBEgANKPHCEnIBvYspcAgUYA60C5hXECkbbWctE7CQnvBSuQdp5hlemrO84FILdW3DrFS2NCIGzxuRAmxsfKmzJhbamwAkieVxCuW29teGOx4WzKOnN8Luxolxf2%2BkYL%2B0DihUyQtnYc1duwx%2BSYNJaR0iPChrdjJaPQv7BhyYzHT1TpyPkEAs7%2BSrLnYuapS6723pXautdPHACKrtJuSQW5k3bl1Tu3dlyrj2P3PYg8TSBXXq2Iwr90CoHfgjLMX8eI/3DIIf%2BglAEkF7KA/quCoHIBgYU%2BBm8%2BwoLQRgspmUww4MgfgmphDiGyOlodWWaiRJZioYhGhy96Gxw1sw0hutYycIxG4PAVBcZGyzHUH4wBRIIFpq9Zi1sJHIDtk7C4IYWZ9OFvIsWBw2KGNSaRaKZpiAhNQMgZAyxVTAneEgg4XINDmD%2BSAXpjNuIWX4oJX26jxJSSsRAOSlyXYxwMerDxYhjxMF2n1M6YQObXzMH8gC%2BKNDxLPnE2gqBTxxTEFQMMF1ZoIyJYSv5JKDy9z2N4JIAcqW0CJMs2J7xyWUsXDy8MfV5r5jwDlPKfKFzHiWLQFsogUYwKBXctZoQ7oUgEO8SFIkNEwtQlySQlIYJRAUEqPAFI0h2jMvkyy1kZ57FtAsChShaom2tQGCAcxbEeKJRnb%2B9qIXp1tWCqyL5U5EqbH1Pl385zXiXHacRQZvBRAuEVGoRC7mJiEKm9NjgMjPkpn1IlGhVBUBWcyn5mAnkhKeu8GIgr%2BXxLwJ6Xsrz3ko0YKsRpvz/lRtCH2qiRKwzNmWtdPtAa7XgtdFGnYapPSPNiCE1UTpQjJVLeWytxLZqbqoJgIlwKuLNgdUM4mu8ypWrwDawNM7HUGU3gvLRRrQ0/wdWGM4DBNXap9XM7N8omCctoCEyJ31NnDRbEwpyqqUXdU1hQ5sV6bUnpfFhU5OE5n62eAmeUQgTgCD2LWVAV9iDdj6lQY6NQrQXKzEwKgB0VhSMDKEJIc5zkgt0dHMM3hzjB17AAKlVjc7miYABioR0DkdbcMPsbzljGB7T8iBg6WNzgg8uJgxbwwED6nkdIBG8h5VAomAASj1JyfU0o/L0AyBkfUYj7neHkMMGg%2BoEfpfR2IWb1aJlysAPKtHPOMbMAySwoCuSkBjKQW0pAACcpAuCJC4G0ZkCWNgJekFwUBGYEtRa4DFrg8W9AaBCzmMM8X2W8YpAJ1Wxn5Rut06kISkh1NQc0gcULNmKldbDD1vYfWsqDZc8Ntpo2htjZc6V7zHsQUScwKoM9brPKwuwb1sBYZpAgLDBFvYUWnXlfadgyaqWKzpYrJtrLtijaqN1aJaFNDVMEEjoi2xPHBAZmq46MxBkLEvhoTYqZgmmsZQwgnUT95Zx0CcAwGmQ5Qf%2BT2FFKG7jTPmagltFeXAY1EggafcqGlKqPzaxQ/2u4HsJXmyzGCbquA0KBwoX9yL5m40THdd4b2CC/k%2BwoLqaQlQhO/nQWIfVMkMG7L2NnFYuSPQXP2WIzZNRpBHLKADI1AMHwF%2Bk4AZHlyXCOb2tsvFkpsscEOFhgyxw7RCW66HHZk2bAzCr5qTZHDeC2iutuZNYlMXHCEu6yVqt1Qaj%2BXUX0XJuTap5cVPOTyYG7KqPYwA3eFUEJga8sMHJTWoyCwLDHkAUhNH%2BI2j32NcU48xbjVWaupFYtzYvFOFu3aWzQ1b/X1t7E2xUnbe2Yt7Aq4l9px2DCnfaRdhkV2Lk3fIX7e7sKS8Ir0Ui1SdWOdc97KcCF0%2BYK/ddP93irEwaFiCBDI4yOVIeMN0kZt4iFCiC1gM3cy4uoZmruKIkK48Axr6tuLl7KGBJUpmAxnBTxOmSk/z2FEVQCiBJmA3HAcgYzq3p30g/B413FCFh3hxshR3lDM3gwxwAmx1bFKnxwSnYlXylHX2%2B23wiT%2B1hQB2RWTCQIynDz%2BnanmkwJdBzlRzwKPAIJPAnTyDfCaljWIJJQJ2rgGg2GwCyyDC6g/xLT0D0DlWIBdAUHRjDCIBhC4RmwdioL1V4jJznwbypxEhpzp1VlsUTAzTd35zg2YTZVyRbEpl2lAmJwfQSiQy9XnxNGzkwwWX%2BDEDwG0mdAgF/A5DQFvkq0ED4zA39gnhC0sAGgZDzAyi5lAj6wyNs16yyP6xyMyO6zyMKIKOKOyJKNyJKNAnGyqJG2qImzqOqI4T/W4RBRICCKYwdBOgaA%2BmUV4XL3egfj1jr0n2nWvFu31X%2BwKm6L6M9Fe3ODXwX2jgnjPR3zdDoJGPQFmMEHmMxmQMhzQJh1NzhRFn2V8IYJ6MDD0IpHJU3m8E8PQnaP4zmDhQuDiJ9isClxXk8SjAnxBWcO2S6LPUQ09WsUmI/TcTOOJz%2BM6M9D8Nxn%2BAjDXR9Fr0ChNC8CYiFz/xMS/gKmJCYiYASNKyEnRhYF2mcNUF2iHAkEBEkBC3cGYCYAZMZKZPRimR0N4WhJLS3xEmuPQFuOBKgClkePQDxLViPV6OOK%2Bibwclp1hW7HAA4DXkTH3GLlQFQBdGSh9zZWdBYANy2jT26MyTAN7BuneEphQj6l7h1PnWMFiDFMDFmSZ0BGWRJHvHrh1FEypEClISEiJhJkEShNpk/HGg5Oe0X19QgLnAUCgGhMeKcVIVFLuW9Iyl9LNnJj%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%2BuPIWF%2Bv%2Bs/NnMIqAvRvAreqHs4G3OBpAFBvBshuhsSzhoRqRqOoPrRsxretIFxoQpACWAICLKJrQuQvCA3E4HDqNUT2uogAuA0k4N4CFEeqTv0EcrNrsokGkCtqUBcttpAHS2PEKiSF1v2pHufo4FCjnCLN7RAcuuuqwtuvzE8AJpKk2A2DmDXuxoPIQS3v2qBp/KvKuCRpjAZFtEkBjFtBvOSwSAi1HpftAuPvXu3pAGfKuBfNhuvIZEkCNSvL0HiwBo2H3tEsPtftkf2vPskeAoMdYdICeTSBcEkCAA%3D%3D%3D), also including code from other answers.
Old version with `(1u<<n) - 1`: https://godbolt.org/z/Gjjqna4Ke)

---

#### Without using `tzcnt`

We can use instructions like `kadd` and `kandn` to do @chtz's suggestion of `(mask-1) & (~mask)`, which is like BMI1 `blsmsk` but *not* including the lowest set bit.  Or we can use non-AVX512 compare/movemask to do the bithack in general-purpose integer registers.

AVX1 compare + movemask is probably better if we need the value in a general-purpose register for `tzcnt` to get the length.  That version of `vpcmpeqb` runs on more ports on Intel than comparing into a `k` mask register, and compare+movemask might be lower latency than cmp_epi8_mask / kmov, and lower latency for `pos` can be very important if lots of later code depends on it, more than out-of-order exec can see past.

```
__m128i zero_above_key_k_bithack(__m128i vec, __m128i separator)
{
    __mmask16 mask = _mm_cmpeq_epi8_mask(vec, separator);
    //mask = (mask-1) & (~mask);  // kmov / lea / andn / kmov.  Use AVX1 cmp/movemask to avoid the first kmov
    mask = _kandn_mask16(mask, _kadd_mask16(mask, -1));  // kadd / kandn  (plus kxnor to create a constant)
     // clang does a masked compare into mask (port 5, 3c latency) instead of KAND (port 0, 1c latency).
    __m128i result = _mm_maskz_mov_epi8(mask, vec);
    return result;
}

__m128i zero_above_key_gpr_bithack(__m128i vec, __m128i separator)
{
    __m128i cmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(vec, separator);
    unsigned mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(cmp);
    mask = (mask-1) & (~mask);  // lea / andn / kmov.
    __m128i result = _mm_maskz_mov_epi8(mask, vec);
    return result;
}
```

GCC compiles them as expected.  Clang uses AVX-512 `vpcmpb k0, xmm,xmm` and needs a `kmovd` instead of `vpmovmskb` even for the GPR version, which is probably worse.  (Round-trip latency for `kmov` is 4 cycles on Ice Lake, according to uops.info's [testing](https://uops.info/html-lat/ICL/KMOVD_K_R32-Measurements.html).

```
zero_above_key_k_bithack(long long __vector(2), long long __vector(2)):
        vpcmpb  k0, xmm0, xmm1, 0
        kxnorw  k1, k1, k1
        kaddw   k1, k0, k1
        kandnw  k1, k0, k1
        vmovdqu8        xmm1{k1}{z}, xmm0
        vmovdqa xmm0, xmm1
        ret

zero_above_key_gpr_bithack(long long __vector(2), long long __vector(2)):
        vpcmpeqb        xmm1, xmm0, xmm1
        vpmovmskb       eax, xmm1
        lea     edx, -1[rax]
        andn    eax, eax, edx
        kmovw   k1, eax
        vmovdqu8        xmm1{k1}{z}, xmm0
        vmovdqa xmm0, xmm1
        ret
```

vs. the `tzcnt` version putting together the pieces with find() and mask_first_n().

```
zero_above_key_ctz_bzhi(long long __vector(2), long long __vector(2)):
        vpcmpeqb        xmm1, xmm0, xmm1
        mov     edx, -1
        vpmovmskb       eax, xmm1
        tzcnt   eax, eax
        bzhi    edx, edx, eax
        kmovw   k1, edx
        vmovdqu8        xmm1{k1}{z}, xmm0
        vmovdqa xmm0, xmm1         # could have operated in-place
        ret
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> thanks to @PeterCordes for the suggestion and expanding + optimizing this answer

Comment: I forgot to mention, AVX512 isn't allowed T_T Because it's not supported on most CPU

Comment: With AVX-512 you don't need `_mm_and_si128`, just use the mask for a zero-masking move.  `result = _mm_maskz_mov_epi8( (1<<tzcnt)-1,  chars )`.  (@HuyLe, hopefully this will be useful to some future readers at some point.)

Comment: chtz suggested in comments under the question: `(cmpmask-1) & (~cmpmask)` is a cheaper way to turn a movemask result into the mask we want than `1<<tzcnt(cmpmask) - 1`.  In a loop, we could even do it in `k` mask registers if we have a mask constant of `1` or `-1` set up, e.g. from `kxnor same,same`.  That saves a `movemask` and a `kmov`, so just `vpcmpb k1, vec, vec` / `kadd k2, k1, k0` / `kandn k2, k1, k2`.  You can hint the compiler toward using `k` instructions with intrinsics like `_kadd_mask16(mask, -1)` and `_kandn_mask16`

Comment: AVX-512 compare-into-mask is `_mm_cmp_epi8_mask(v,v, _MM_CMPINT_EQ)` aka `_mm_cmpeq_epi8_mask(v,v)`.  Compare for not-equal is also available but in this case the mask-generation is easiest with EQ rather than NE.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/E344YrxqK uses kadd / kandn, indeed saving a couple instructions vs. the non-k-intrinisc version.  But AVX     `vpcmpeqb  xmm2, xmm0, xmm1` / `vpmovmskb eax, xmm2` instead of compare into k0 / kmovd eax ,k0 has fewer port 5 uops (with `lea` / `andn` / `kmov`), so a port bottleneck of only 2c throughput on Ice lake.  But mixed with other code, fewer front-end uops probably wins.

Comment: @PeterCordes feel free to edit this answer or post another one if you think there's a better AVX-512 way. I've got to go for now, and my AVX-512 knowledge is very limited anyway. Thanks for all your efforts so far.

Comment: Ok, finally finished an edit.  The text I ended up adding at the top is already pretty long, and I had more that I might post as my own answer at some point.

Answer (score 2):

The following code (requiring only SSE 4.1), masks out every byte following the first occurrence of `char c` in `string`:

```
__m128i maskString(__m128i string, char c) {
    // find every occurrence of `c`:
    __m128i compareMask = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(string, _mm_set1_epi8(c));
    // always generate a `-1` for the lower half, 
    // and a `-1` for the upper half if the lower half is zero (i.e. if it would carry):
    __m128i minus_one = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(_mm_bslli_si128(compareMask, 8), _mm_setzero_si128());
    // `~compareMask & (compareMask-1)` as if computed as 128bit subtraction.
    // Subtraction makes `0xff` of every byte below the first occurrence of `c` in `string`, anding with `~compareMask` clears every remaining `0xff` and `0xfe`
    __m128i andMask = _mm_andnot_si128(compareMask, _mm_add_epi64(compareMask, minus_one));

    // apply mask to string and return:
    return _mm_and_si128(andMask, string);
}
```

Godbolt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Tnsj1sf46

N.B.: If you need the length of the key anyways, OP's original code is probably fine (loading data from cache is usually cheap).

Comment: I think you can use `palignr` (`_mm_alignr_epi8(compareMask, set1(-1))`) instead of `_mm_bslli_si128` / `_mm_cmpeq_epi64` to shift ones into the bottom instead of zeros.  Or better `_mm_unpacklo_epi64(set1(-1), compareMask)`

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I need the `pcmpeqq` anyways to create the carry `-1` for the upper half, if the lower half is zero.

Comment: Oh right, the first compare is just the byte element size.  I was thinking `compareMask` was the result of checking the low half of that for zero, but you're right, we can shift first and get our low-half `-1` for free.  So yes, `_mm_bslli_si128` is the ideal choice, not unpacking with the zero vector we already have, unless AVX1 is available to avoid a register copy movdqa.

Comment: Turns out the OP needs the length of the key (probably so they know where the value starts), so this unfortunately doesn't let them optimize away the `movemask` / `std::countr_zero`.  This might be the cheapest if we really want to avoid loading from `.rodata`, and probably lower critical-path latency, but is more uops than `neg / vpand v, mem` on top of the already required pcmp/pmovmskb/tzcnt

Answer (score 2):

One could get the position by `_mm_minpos_epu16` by shifting so the high bit of the min value is concatenated with the word-index, forming the desired byte-index.  This requires that there's only one separator, otherwise a later `00FF` is less than an earlier `FF00`.

(We also need to preprocess, because `00 00` words would be smaller than either 00FF or FF00.)

```
   // key:12312 --> 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 ... -> min_idx = idx=01|FF00
   // kk:131232 --> 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 ... -> min_idx = idx=01|00FF
   __m128i mask = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(key, separator);
   // convert the 0000 -> FFFF
   //             00FF -> 00FE
   //             FF00 -> FEFF
   mask = _mm_sub_epi16(mask, _mm_set1_epi16(1));  // or add -1, cheaper constant
   __m128i min_idx = _mm_minpos_epu16(mask);

   // shift right to get min_idx = 3 for the first case
   // min_idx = 2 for the second case
   min_idx = _mm_srli_epi32(min_idx, 15);  // keep high bit of min val + 2*idx

   // broadcast the byte zero everywhere
   min_idx = _mm_shuffle_epi8(min_idx, _mm_setzero_si128());
   
   // make the mask
   __m128i mask = _mm_cmplt_epi8(k0123456789, min_idx);
   
   // use the mask
   key = _mm_and_si128(key, mask);
```

One can as well broadcast the byte #2 (i.e. the index from `minpos` after)

```
   __m128i min_idx = _mm_minpos_epu16(mask);
   min_idx = _mm_add_epi32(min_idx, min_idx);
   min_idx = _mm_shuffle_epi8(min_idx, _mm_set1_epi8( 2 ));
```

---

But as pointed in the comments, this would not work readily for cases where there are two or more separators.

One can try to equalise `00FF` and `FF00`, e.g. by

```
   __m128i mask_s = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(key, separator);
   __m128i tmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi16(mask_s, _mm_setzero_si128());
   // now 0000 -> FFFF
   //     00FF -> 0000
   //     FF00 -> 0000
   pos = _mm_minpos_epi16(tmp);
```

But now the LSB needs to be detected separately.
One can still use minpos that has the wrong granularity as in

```
   __m128i word_mask = _mm_cmplt_epi8(k0011223344556677, pos_broadcasted_as_int16);
   word_mask = _mm_or_si128(word_mask, mask_s);
```

Comment: There can be more than one `:` in the 16-byte window which starts at the start of this line.   `00FF` is smaller than `FF00` so that will mess up the minimum.  Also, `00 00` is smaller than either of those, so even for strings with a single `:`, you need to invert the compare result or else minpos will just find a 0 word.  BTW, `vector_of_all_twos = _mm_set1_epi8( 2 )`.