Zero remaining Bytes after first Zero in SSE Register
For this question, I will use the notation 1 for a byte with all ones (0xFF) and 0 for a byte with all zeros.
I am looking for a way to zero the remaining bytes in a SSE register after the first zero byte using SSE 4.2 intrinsics:
Example Input:
1111'1101'1011'1000
Desired Output:
1111'1100'0000'0000
Please note, that the data should remain in the SSE register. This is an trivial task to do in a simple byte array!

Note that C++ does not have features to access SSE registers. If you ask about concrete compiler "intrinsic"s (or whatever a concrete compiler names those) then name the compiler/platform and tag it correctly.

@ÖöTiib I can't follow what I should add exactly. If you include tmmintrin.h in C(++) in any modern compiler, you will get access to the same set of SSE intrinsic functions. The platform is also given, since only x86 processors support SEE.

By "the first" zero byte, do you mean the least significant or most significant byte (when seeing the register as a 128bit integer). And do you have just SSE1, or SSE4.2 or something in between?

@chtz I have SSE 4.2. With "first" I actually mean the least significant byte, since I am used to using the setr functions.

@Crigges Just be clear. For example to me it looks tmmintrin.h is for SSE3 and nmmintrin.h is needed for SSE4.2. Yet in question you talk about SSE4.2 and in comment about tmmintrin.h

I think the corresponding bit-twiddling hack is x & ~(x+1) or x & (-2 - x), but unfortunately, there is no 128bit addition/subtraction. There was a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77800999/fastest-way-to-mask-out-bytes-higher-than-separator-position-with-simd/

SSE4.2 provides string instructions returning masks or indexes. In your case this should work:
// generate a mask of `0xff` until first `0` entry of `a`:
__m128i mask_until_first_zero(__m128i a)
{
    // checks where `a` and `a` are equal and valid (i.e., until the first `0` byte):
    return _mm_cmpistrm(a, a, _SIDD_UNIT_MASK); // <-- _SIDD_UNIT_MASK to create byte mask instead of bit mask
    //            ^   ^-- `m` to return a mask
    //            `------ `i` for implicit length string
}


You can do:

_mm_movemask_epi8 to swtitch to bits in general purpose registers
bitwise negate and lzcnt to find the position of that 0 (use _BitScanReverse if no BMI allowed)
Do _mm_loadu_si128 from the predefined memory array of 16 0x00 bytes and 16 0xFF bytes using 16 minus the zero position as the index.

The las step contradicts to your requirement

Please note, that the data should remain in the SSE register. This is an trivial task to do in a simple byte array!

But if that requirements is for performance reason, then I don't see a way to do this more efficiently while staying away from the memory operands.

I like this answer since it requires no looping, since lzcnt is constant. However I would't use _mm_loadu_si128 and instead use a register with ones and shift it to the left.

@Crigges, up to you, but I'm afraid there's no usable variable byte 128-bit shift.
Maybe you can shift 64-bit SSE value using _mm_sll_epi64 and all ones nibbles and then make it 128-bit bytes using _mm_unpacklo_epi8(val, val), or do something else like this, but I'm afraid it would be less efficient.

I didn't test it out yet, but I thought _mm_slli_si128  would do the job.

lzcnt finds the most significant zero doesn't it? If I understood the question correctly, OP wants the least significant.

@Crigges _mm_slli_si128 requires a compile-time constant.

@chtz, well then tzcnt / _BitScanForward

If you want to avoid memory operands, you could do something like _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(_mm256_set1_epi8(pos), index) where pos is the result of tzcnt and index is a constant array {0,1,...,15} (maybe something needs to be the other way around, I did not check).
